Limit number of returned records on OneToMany in Spring-Data
I want to implement a recentOrders function in my spring-data app. So for a given customer I want to retrieve the last 5 orders the customer has everytime. But have a separate field that is the entire orders list that I can fetch as needed.
I have the OneToMany mappings working fine, but what I can't find a way to do is to tell spring to only bring back the last 5 orders for the given customer. There doesn't seem to be anyway to apply a limit to the OneToMany relationship. Yes, I could do custom code, but then I have to essentially go entirely around the OneToMany relationship and essentially map the connection directly, which seems to defeat the point.
Is there really no way to implement this type of functionality when doing this work in Spring? It's already going to issue a new query for the orders table for each customer records, so why can't we append annotation based qualifiers to the generation of that query?
